# Exception while running cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber

I am getting the below exception while running feature file

Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong type at constant pool index
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:164)
        at cucumber.api.java8.En.Given(En.java:190)
        at stepdefinitions.steps.(steps.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.buildWorld(JavaBackend.java:131)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.buildBackendWorlds(Runtime.java:140)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:38)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong type at constant pool index
        at sun.reflect.ConstantPool.getMemberRefInfoAt0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.ConstantPool.getMemberRefInfoAt(Unknown Source)
        at cucumber.runtime.java8.ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector.getTypeString(ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.java8.ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector.getGenericTypes(ConstantPoolTypeIntrospector.java:27)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.Java8StepDefinition.(Java8StepDefinition.java:45)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:162)
        ... 23 more

Comment: can you please tell us what your feature file looks like and what the code is

Comment: can you please tell us what your feature file looks like and what the code is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an incompatible version of `cucumber-java8` and your JVM. To do it's job `cucumber-java8` depends on some implementation details (constant pool layout) of the JVM. Upgrade your cucumber or downgrade your JDK. Alternatively consider using the annotation based step definitions provided by `cucumber-java`.